# How to exit views function if queryset not found not found in database

Tags: python, regex, django

I have two apps in my django project "card" and "blog"

my project urls.py is :

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'', include(card.urls)),
path('', include('blog.urls')),]
```

url.py for "card" app is:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^card/$', views.cardindex, name='cardindex'),
re_path(r'^(?P<card_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.carddet, name='carddetail'),]
```

views.py for "card" app is:

```
def cardindex(request):
....

def carddet(request, card_url_var):
try:
    url_carddetails = carddata.objects.get(page_end_url=card_url_var)
except carddata.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Card you are looking for, does not exists")
return render(request, 'card.html', {'url_carddetails':url_carddetails})
```

Now urls.py for "blog" apps is:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^blog/$', views.articleindex, name='articleindex'),
re_path(r'^(?P<art_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.articledet, name='articledetail'),]
```

viws.py for blog apps is:
    def articleindex(request):
    ....

```
def articledet(request, art_url_var):
try:
    url_articledetails = articledata.objects.get(art_end_url=art_url_var)
except articledata.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Article you are looking for, does not exists")
return render(request, 'article.html', {'url_articledetails':url_articledetails})
```

When I request urls that are in "page_end_url" column of "carddata" model the code works fine. But when I request urls that are in "art_end_url" column of "articledata" model it returns Http404 "Card you are looking for, does not exists".

For Example:
If I request example.com/new-year-card-2018
The Code works fine because "new-year-card-2018" exists in "page_end_url" column.

But If i request example.com/best-designs-of-2018
The url "/best-design-of-2018" whis is saved "art_end_url" attribute of "articledata" model. The code returns Http404 "Card you are looking for, does not exists"

So please tell me that, is there is way to exit carddet function in "card" views.py file, if requested url i.e "card_url_var" does not match with "page_end_url".
 I am a newbie in django.
Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You request keeps calling the first URL matches from your URLs patterns.

Actually, these 2 URLs are almost same:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<card_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.carddet, name='carddetail'),]

re_path(r'^(?P<art_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.articledet, name='articledetail'),]
```

This `(?P<card_url_var>[-\w.]+)` is waiting for a slug : `/slug-slug/`

And also this `(?P<art_url_var>[-\w.]+)`: `/slug-slug/`.
So Django will look for the first match URL, obviously the first will match. What you can do is add something different in each, like:

```
re_path(r'^card/(?P<card_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.carddet, name='carddetail'),]

re_path(r'^article/(?P<art_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.articledet, name='articledetail'),]
```

Comment: PS: I have updated the code. card and article pages are to index all cards and articles. The Problem here is this i card_url_var to capture the url string requested, so that i can check it in my database and save the requested query in variable url_carddetails, to fill the values from database in template requested. and I do not want card and article detail pages url to be the sub folder of /card and /article.

Comment: `/card and /article` are just string to avoid confusing, it's not a subfolder at all. this doesn't change anything by adding them except the URLs displayed in a browser. name your arguments, and retrieve them in view with that name

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

try:
    ...
except:
    return redirect(reverse('name-of-url'))
```

more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect)